# Meaning of "non-normative"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, figures-of-speech

What's the meaning of "a *non-normative* document"?

Does "non-normative" mean "casual"?

What's the significant difference between a normative document and a non-normative one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I typically see this in reference to standards and technical documents. A *normative* definition or statement is one that should be taken as authoritative or imperative (i.e., a *should* or a *must*), while a *non-normative* one is one that bears no such restriction.

Synonyms for *normative* would include *prescriptive*, so synonyms of *non-normative* could range from *descriptive* to *declarative* to *informal* or *casual*, depending on context.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, it means "informal" or "nonstandard", as from the [Free Online Dictionary:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nonnormative)

> Not based on a norm

Comment: I was going to reply that this was just wrong, and the Free Online Dictionary was equally wrong, because it is certainly not how I would use the word. But looking up the word in COCA, I find that the vast majority of uses there are exactly according to this definition, so I was wrong.