# What does "non-normative" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

From the [ECMAScript language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) *ECMA-262 page 1 Section 4*

> This section contains a **non-normative** overview of the ECMAScript
>   language

The text goes on to say

> ECMAScript is an object-oriented programming language for performing
>   computations...

What does "non-normative" mean in this context?

Comment: The organization itself probably defines *normative* and *non-normative* somewhere, but if it's anything like the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/WAI/lexicon/#nonnorm)'s documents, normative means something like "the actual specifications" and non-normative means something like "tips, guidelines, etc. that are easier to read than the actual specs, but you must still rely on the actual specs; this stuff isn't authoritative".

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of `non-normative`?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28882/what-is-the-meaning-of-non-normative)

Comment: @ColinFine, Wow, this duplicate has more upvotes then my original.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From [sitepoint.com](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?618221-In-the-W3C-what-is-non-normative):

> A normative section is a formal part of the recommendation. It contains rules that everyone must follow.
>
> A non-normative, or informative, section contains additional information, advice and suchlike that isn't a formal part of the standard. That doesn't mean the information is less important, but it's not binding in the same way as the normative sections.

A good synonym, then, seems to be *informal*.

Comment: I'd have said the synonym is *informational*, as opposed to the "normative" sections being either *defining* or *prescriptive* (or *recommendational*, if I can get away with that one).

Comment: Aren't the normative sections informational, though?

Comment: Well yes - that's why I said *as opposed to*. The implication being that the "non-normative" sections are **merely** informational.

Comment: Other synonyms could be *explanatory*, *descriptive* (as opposed to *prescriptive*), *unofficial*, or *expository*.

Comment: I happen to read a spec on MQTT protocol where port numbers assigned to MQTT are mentioned as non-normative comment. Isn't that wrong? Shouldn't that be normative? Part of spec " Non-normative comment : TCP ports 8883 and 1883 are registered with IANA for MQTT TLS and non-TLS communication respectively.

Answer (score 15):

'Normative' means 'what you should do' or 'what you must do', the rules that you are supposed to follow.

So 'non-normative' means 'what is recommended to be done', the suggestions on how to do things well (within the formal specifications laid out in the 'normative' part). It can also mean 'how people generally do things' whatever the formal rules say.

In a technical manual, something that is called 'non-normative' is most likely going to be general tips and examples on how to do what you want rather than a reference grammar or technical schema.

Answer (score 1):

I was also researching about this word. And seeing the answers above make me clear in this way:

- Normative: Norms and principals that you must follow.
- Non-normative: No norms and principals but you may kindly follow.